# How to style a link which wrote with echo?

Tags: php, css

I would like to the links will be bold in a div, but the links are in a variable which wrote down with echo.

```
<tr>
  <td rowspan="1" colspan="4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 310px;" align="center">
  <div class="description">
    <b>Short description: </b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="4" style="vertical-align: top; height: 100px; width: 310px;" class="style2">
    <br>
      <?php print ($_SESSION['description']); ?><br>
    <br>
    <hr>
  </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The link is in the `$_SESSION['description']`.
The css:

```
.description a:link {
    text-decoration: bold;
}

.description a:visited {
    text-decoration: bold;
}

.description a:hover {
    text-decoration: bold;
}

.description a:active {
    text-decoration: bold;
}
```

I already tried some ways, but the style "can't see" the links which wrote with echo. How can I solve this?

Comment: Also can you show `$_SESSION['description']` value?

Comment: PHP just echo's out HTML. There's no difference in styling a link whether you've echo'd it from a PHP variable or written it out directly in HTML.

Comment: where is the <a></a> tag

Comment: That's some messed up HTML structure there...table rows in divs etc. Validate your HTML!

Comment: It's `font-weight: bold;` not `text-decoration: bold;`

Comment: $_SESSION['description'] value is e.g.: This is the description and <a href='link.php'>this is a link</a>. More text...

Comment: Yes, thanks Adrenaxus, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace all**

```
text-decoration: bold;
```

**with**

```
font-weight:bold
```

**UPDATE**
A downvote, seriously? He is putting the link in description class, which only needs to be fixed

Now style **can see** (after replace as I said)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .description a:link {
      font-weight: bold
    }
    .description a:visited {
      font-weight: bold
    }
    .description a:hover {
      font-weight: bold
    }
    .description a:active {
      font-weight: bold
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 310px;" align="center">
      <div class="description">
        <b>Short description: </b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="4" style="vertical-align: top; height: 100px; width: 310px;" class="style2">
      <br>
      <a href="google.com">google</a>
      <br>
      <hr>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</body>
</head>
```

and what he was doing

```html
<html>

<head>
<style>
.description a:link {
    text-decoration: bold;
}

.description a:visited {
    text-decoration: bold;
}

.description a:hover {
    text-decoration: bold;
}

.description a:active {
    text-decoration: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="1" colspan="4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 310px;" align="center">
  <div class="description">
    <b>Short description: </b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="4" style="vertical-align: top; height: 100px; width: 310px;" class="style2">
    <br>
     <a href = "google.com">google</a>
    <br>
    <hr>
  </div>
  </td>
</tr>

</body></head>
```

**PLEASE CHECK BEFORE DOWNVOTING**

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Just replaced text-decoration: bold; with font-weight: bold;. And now works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="description">
     <b>Short description: </b></td> </tr> <tr> ....
```

is no valid html!

**FIX IT TO**

```
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 310px;" align="center">

   <b>Short description: </b></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="4" style="vertical-align: top; height: 100px; width: 310px;" class="style2">
        <div class="description">    
          <br>
             <?php print ($_SESSION['description']); ?><br>
          <br>
          <hr>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I fixed it, but nothing happened. The link works, but the style isn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a><?php echo $_SESSION['description']; ?></a>
```

Now it become a link, and you can put style like

```
a:link{}
```